# Can access dataRow["name"] but not dataTable.Rows[0]["name"]

Tags: c#

I have:

```
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow["name"] = "John";
```

This works:

```
        String test = dataRow["name"].ToString();
```

but this doesn't:

```
        String test = dataTable.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
```

Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you didn't add the new row to the table.

```
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow(); 
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
dataRow["name"] = "John";
```

Comment: Oh my NewRow is a method of this datatable couldn't Microsoft consider that it should be added to datatable but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow["name"] = "John";

// Add this:
dataTable.AddRow(dataRow);
```